# Can't deploy my website onto Heroku - is Numpy causing the issue?

Tags: python, numpy, heroku

My website is currently using Heroku-18 stack, which is deprecated. I therefore need to redeploy my site to have it up to date (Heroku-22 stack) but I'm getting errors when trying. The log mentions numpy related errors numerous times, so I assume it could be the source of my problem.

I've already looked online for some solutions but none of them have worked. I notably tried upgrading pip, changing the python version in my runtime.txt file, reinstalling numpy but nothing worked.

Before redeploying my website, the python version in runtime.txt was python-3.7.0. It is currently set to python-3.9.13.
Numpy is installed and the version is 1.18.1.

Here are some of the errors I'm getting:

> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mywebsite.git'

> error: Command "gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o.d" failed with exit status 1

> ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
> remote:              Failed to build numpy

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy

How can I fix these errors?
Also, could it be someting else non numpy-related that causes the failure of the deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve the issue. Many dependencies were outdated. I had to use python-3.9.14 version, upgrade psycopg2-binary to v2.9.3 and scipy to v1.6.